# Difference between border and border-style

Tags: css, primefaces

I remove all borders of my primefaces panelgrid component using these ways:

First one:

```
.table, table td {
    border-style: hidden !important;
}
```

Another one:

```
.table, table tr, table td {
    border: none !important;
}
```

What is the difference between border and border-style property?

Comment: this link should explain all http://www.impressivewebs.com/comparison-css-border-style/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`border` is a shorthand notation for setting border properties.

See the details at: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-border-shorthands

Answer (score 0):

`border-style` defines type (or style) of border: solid, dotted, dashed, hidden, etc.

`border` defines all border attributes in one definition, so it includes above style and also color and width like this (order of attributes is unimportant):
`border: <width> <style> <color>;`

Comment: `hidden` is a valid value, even in CSS 2.1. The order of the values in the `border` value is insignificant.